# Helper function inside class - pros and cons for various approaches

Tags: python, class, architecture

I am considering three ways to implement helpers function, i.e. a function that is only called by a specific method inside a class. The options are:

1. Define an external function
2. Define a function of the class
3. Define a function inside the calling function

Here is a minimal code showing the three options:

```
class test(object):
    def mytest1(self, n):
        return outloop(n)


    def mytest2(self, n):
        return self.inloop(n)


    def inloop(self, n):
        if n < 0:
            return 0
        return self.inloop(n - 1) + 1


    def mytest3(self, n):
        def innerloop(n):
            if n < 0:
                return 0
            return innerloop(n - 1) + 1
        return innerloop(n)


def outloop(n):
    if n < 0:
        return 0
    return outloop(n - 1) + 1
```

I've tested performances and all three seems to be roughly the same. My question: Can you share some considerations I should be aware of in choosing between the three options?

I'll appreciate getting architectural insight and guidance as to when you think each should be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From an object-oriented design standpoint it is better when the caller combines method calls to achieve its results rather than the called class itself.  This creates more flexibility in the code for the caller which is generally a good thing in a world of constantly changing requirements.

That said in terms of the helper function defined in class the question is is the helper function intrinsic or essential to the functioning of the method called.  In other words does it make any sense to split the functionality out and create two useful functions or do you really only have one useful function.

In terms of defining the helper function as an external function related functions should be put together inside a class to make code maintenance easier.  Keeping in mind that any class should follow the [Single Responsibility Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) and have one and only one reason to change.

Answer (score 0):

It will be easier to test if you just use a plain function outside the class.